# Performance chrome dev tools not able to see the ts source files in Angular

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to improve an app's performance, I used to record with the chrome dev performance tool and then review the bottom-up section and click on the link at the right side to check where is the code that is taking time.

But now I am trying to do it again and I am not able to click en see the the source TS files:

For example instead of seeing the ngFactory.js I was able to see the .ts file and when clicking on the link I was able to see which line of code was taking too much time.

[image: Performance tool]

Comment: Do you have sourcemaps enabled for your project? Additionally, I'm running into an issue where I cannot click on these file links, even though they show the real filename + line number (in Chrome 89.0.4389.90).

Comment: Yes, I have them enabled, I am able to see them in sources tab.